# Insert into table, case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert into new table (2 columns) Distinct description from other table and in second row case.

So like:

```
Insert into @Temp1
Select distinct description from Table1,
CASE
WHEN aaa then 1
When bbb then 2
END
```

So basically for every inserted value in first column, in second column goes one of several possible values, depending on first value.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Looks like you are missing the `input_expression` from your [Simple CASE expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) and have the `FROM` in the wrong place..

```
INSERT INTO @Temp1
SELECT DISTINCT description,
                CASE description
                  WHEN aaa THEN 1
                  WHEN bbb THEN 2
                END
FROM   Table1
```

Of course if `aaa` etc are constants rather than derived from other columns in `Table1` such that the second column can be deterministically derived from the first column (and it isn't going to be altered in future updates) there might not be any point in storing it at all. You can define the table variable with a computed column definition or simply use the `CASE` expression when `SELECT`-ing from it.

Example of the computed column case

```
DECLARE @Temp1 TABLE (
  [description] VARCHAR(50),
  [calcColumnExample] AS CASE description
       WHEN 'aaa' THEN 1
       WHEN 'bbb' THEN 2
     END 
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to make like this:

```
Insert into @Temp1
Select distinct description,
CASE description
WHEN 'aaa' then 1
When 'bbb' then 2
END
 from Table1
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to CASE, you could also use a join to an in-line table, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  t.Description,
  x.SpecialValue
FROM Table1 t
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 'aaa', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bbb', 2 UNION ALL
    …
  ) x (Description, SpecialValue) ON t.Description = x.Description
```